# .htaccess 301 redirect workaround

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

A client is placing a recruitment advert in the press featuring a custom url:

e.g. www.clientsname.com/newjob

...this page does not exist on the site but when people visit it they want it to redirect to their recruitment page:

e.g. www.clientsname.com/recruitment

This is how their .htaccess file currently looks:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=PublicDisplayPage&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

...I don't pretend to understand what the above does! However, I tried the following for the redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /newjob www.clientsname.com/recruitment
```

but this resulted in this url:

http://www.clientsname.com/recruitment?action=PublicDisplayPage&url=newjob

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get it to redirect to just *www.clientsname.com/recruitment* - i.e. without the *?action=PublicDisplayPage&url=newjob*

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Redirect` directive is a mod_alias directive, and the routing to `/index.php` is via mod_rewrite. Both modules processed the same URI, so they both mangle the URI. In this case, you need to stick with just mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?newjob(.*)$ /recruitment$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=PublicDisplayPage&url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's important  to have the redirect before the routing rule, otherwise the redirect will never happen.

Comment: +1 `It's important to have the redirect before the routing rule` didn't know before :) thanks man.